# Names having same ID should come in one cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, imacros

I have different ids for for different names in excel. Many names having the the same ids. How to get all the names having same id in one cell correspondingly. I need formula. Please help me out

Comment: Hey Chandra, welcome to SO. Please provide information what you have accomplished so far. Also, your description will not be sufficient to help you out. Post an example worksheet to visualise your setup. Here is some [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get you started.

Comment: show some sample data. Show us what you want the the formula to do.
Then please tell us what you tried and what did not work.

Comment: I have number of IPs. Some IPs having 2G,3G and 4G and some IPs having 2G and 3G and remaining IPs having only 2G. So, I want the IPs  list having all the technologies in one cell. Ex:Column 1 having tech and column 2 having IPs. I want the all technologies in one cell in colum c.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? It'd have been nicer if you had shown your progress so far, but hope to be of help like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Concatenate_Names()

Dim a As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

i = 1
x = *[number of items in your list]*

For a = 1 To *[number of unique values in a separate list]*

    i = 1

    Do While i <= x

        'The cell references should be dependent on where your unique  value list is,
        'as well as where the full list is.

        '"a" for the unique values, "i" for the full list - matching IDs

        If Cells(a, 8).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value Then

            '"a" for the unique values, "i" for the full list - appending names

            Cells(a, 9).Value = Cells(a, 9).Value & Cells(i, 2).Value

        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the VBA aproach, you still can use recursive functions :

1. Add column to store a semantic representation with key / values, in my example, the representation schema is : `@Key1:Value11[;Value12...][@Key2:Value21[;Value22...]...]`

   The formula bellow recursively builds such a representation, the last row will contain the complete representation of pairs key / values :

   `=IF(IFERROR(FIND("@"&A2&":";C1);-1)=-1;C1&"@"&A2&":"&B2;IF(IFERROR(FIND("@";C1;FIND("@"&A2&":";C1)+1);-2) = -2;LEFT(C1;FIND("@";C1;FIND("@"&A2&":";C1)+1)-1)&";"&B2;LEFT(C1;FIND("@";C1;FIND("@"&A2&":";C1)+1)-1)&";"&B2&RIGHT(C1;LEN(C1)-FIND("@";C1;FIND("@";C1;FIND("@"&A2&":";C1)+1)) + 1)))`
2. Add a second new column to retrieve values associeted to current row / key, the formula uses the last computed representation :

   `=IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(INDEX(C:C;MATCH(REPT("z";255);C:C));LEN(INDEX(C:C;MATCH(REPT("z";255);C:C)))-FIND("@"&A2;INDEX(C:C;MATCH(REPT("z";255);C:C)))-1-LEN(A2));FIND("@";RIGHT(INDEX(C:C;MATCH(REPT("z";255);C:C));LEN(INDEX(C:C;MATCH(REPT("z";255);C:C)))-FIND("@"&A2;INDEX(C:C;MATCH(REPT("z";255);C:C)))-1-LEN(A2));2)-1);RIGHT(INDEX(C:C;MATCH(REPT("z";255);C:C));LEN(INDEX(C:C;MATCH(REPT("z";255);C:C)))-FIND("@"&A2;INDEX(C:C;MATCH(REPT("z";255);C:C)))-1-LEN(A2)))`

The result should look like this :

```
Key  Value   Representation                   Values
 1     a     @1:a                             a;e;i
 2     b     @1:a@2:b                         b;h
 3     c     @1:a@2:b@3:c                     c;j
 1     e     @1:a;e@2:b@3:c                   a;e;i
 5     f     @1:a;e@2:b@3:c@5:f               f
 6     g     @1:a;e@2:b@3:c@5:f@6:g           g
 2     h     @1:a;e@2:b;h@3:c@5:f@6:g         b;h
 1     i     @1:a;e;i@2:b;h@3:c@5:f@6:g       a;e;i
 3     j     @1:a;e;i@2:b;h@3:c;j@5:f@6:g     c;j
```